# NiFi cannot connect to itself via RPG in an secured mode

Tags: ssl, certificate, apache-nifi

i have running some NiFi stand alone instances in secured mode. connecting each other vie site-to-site is working fine, i'm not able to get a connection to itself.

let's assume some nifi instances

```
 - https://my-nifi-1.local:9443/nifi
 - https://my-nifi-2.local:9443/nifi
 - https://my-nifi-3.local:9443/nifi
```

doing a remote connection between `https://my-nifi-1.local:9443/nifi` and `https://my-nifi-2.local:9443/nifi` and `https://my-nifi-3.local:9443/nifi` works properly.

if my flow sends some data via "Remote connections Output Port" to a Remot-Process-Group on the top level of the flow, then its not working.

**ErrorMessage**: `forbidden - Site-to-Site is not secure`.

i tried to configure my RPG using `https://my-nifi-1.local:9443/nifi` or `https://localhost:9443/nifi`.

THX for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found the solution
Each instances CN has to be added to the users and also there are some policies to apply
Thanks to Bryan Bende I could figure it out -> https://bryanbende.com/development/2016/08/30/apache-nifi-1.0.0-secure-site-to-site